# Can Lord Vishnu exhausts one's Karmic seeds according to Vishishta Advaita?

Tags: vishishtadvaita, sharanagati

According  to Vishishta Advaita following are the means for liberation-

1. Primary - Self Surrender (Sharangati).
2. Secondary - Devotion (Bhakti).

For now my primary concern is Self surrender. One can't be liberated from birth-death cycle without exhausting one's Karmic seeds, i.e impressions to cause further material events or existence (Sanchita Karmas). God don't (or can't?) exhaust one's sanchita karmas then how & why self surrender work? Can self surrender exhaust Sanchita Karmas? If not, why self surrender is a valid method for liberation?

Comment: Sri Vaishnavas believe that once you perform Sharanagati, Sriman Narayana destroys your entire stock of Sanchita Karmas, so that you only have Prarabdha Karmas left to experience.

Comment: Interesting. You can answer @KeshavSrinivasan